# Implement F# interface member with Unit return type in C#

Tags: f#, null, unit-type

Suppose I've defined the following interface in F#:

```
type IFoo<'T> = 
  abstract member DoStuff : 'T -> unit
```

If I implement this in C# I need the method signature to be:

```
public void DoStuff<T>(T arg) {...}
```

What I really want to do is reference FSharp.Core and then use:

```
public Unit DoStuff<T>(T arg) {...}
```

This would simplify other code because I wouldn't have to deal with Action vs Func. I'm guessing that there isn't any clean way to achieve this? How about some evil hacks?

Comment: And you'd rather deal with nasty FSharpFuncs from C#, and unfamiliarity from C# devs? You could probably implement your own 'Unit' type and use that, but it is really a horrible idea.

Comment: None of the above requires use of FSharpFuncs from C#. Unfamiliarity is a problem that won't go away unless tackled....by familiarisation! I agree that my own Unit type would be a horrible idea: RX has already introduced its own version; the world does not need another :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transformation of `Unit` to `void` is baked into the compiler. There's a [`FuncConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340268.aspx) class in F# Core for converting between `FSharpFunc` and `Converter`. What about defining a similar class to convert `Action<T>` to `Func<T, Unit>`?

```cs
static class ActionConvert {
    private static readonly Unit Unit = MakeUnit();

    public static Func<T, Unit> ToFunc<T>(Action<T> action) {
        return new Func<T, Unit>(x => { action(x); return Unit; });
    }

    private static Unit MakeUnit() {
        //using reflection because ctor is internal
        return (Unit)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Unit), true);
    }
}
```

Then you could do

```cs
var foo = new Foo<int>();
var func = ActionConvert.ToFunc<int>(foo.DoStuff);
```

You could probably even forego the `Unit` instance and return `null` instead.

Comment: That'll do the trick, thanks! Still wish we could choose to use Unit when implementing interfaces. I'm finding myself using it in other places.