# Properly implement F# Unit in C#

Tags: c#, f#, functional-programming, unit-type

This question is not about C#/F# compatibility as in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928963/implement-f-interface-member-with-unit-return-type-in-c-sharp).

I'd like to know the proper way to implement a type like [F# Unit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx) in place of using `void`.

Obviously I'll discard this result and I'll not expose this type to the outside world.

Wondering if an empty class could impersonate this role.

```
internal class Unit
{
}
```

For example in [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/Unit.cs) library, the author used a `struct`.

Is there any benefit in this choice?

Comment: A struct value and an always-null class value are roughly identical in terms of performance, but the former can be limited to a singular value while the latter cannot (null and non-null). `internal abstract class Unit` would be a better idea...

Comment: You might be interested in the RX implementation: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Core/Reactive/Unit.cs

Comment: @idjarn, sorry I've not understood what you mean... You're saying that a value type is better because can't be set to `null` (if not explicitly boxed)?

Comment: @Foole Dude, put your comment in an answer box, that's perfect!  :-)

Comment: +1 @Foole, this was very useful to me. I had completely forgotten of `Unit` implementation of **Rx.NET**. I see that also this implementation is `struct`-based, maybe for the same reason just quoted in the last comment?

Comment: Agree with @ScottLowe... I would add a little example with a function returning the default singleton with `return Unit.Default`.

Comment: @gsscoder : The point is to allow a singular value. For value types this is easy, since they can't be null; if boxed, values are then of type `System.Object` rather than of the value type. The reference types are trickier, since null is always a possible value; that being the case, `null` is the ideal sentinal value, and the goal becomes to make _non-null_ values impossible, hence the recommendation for `abstract` or `static` on the class.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/sasa/code/ci/default/tree/Sasa/Empty.cs

Comment: @ildjarn +1 I really appreciated your clarification. Your point is interesting, but the `struct` solution seems more idiomatic (to the extent of how much it could be doing such thing in C#).

Comment: @gsscoder : No problem. Re-reading my comments now, it appeared I was advocating for use of a reference type, when that's not actually the case (value types are awesome!); I only meant to point out that if you go with a reference type then `static class` or `abstract class` with a private constructor would be necessary in order to disallow non-null instances. :-]

Comment: @gsscoder boxing does not allow you to have a null value for a value type; it gives you a null reference whose static type is some reference type (object, IComparable, what have you).  How would you create a null int by boxing?  What would you box to get that null value?

Comment: @phoog, yes, this is right. I expressed myself really bad, sorry. Writing a thing, while thinking at `Nullable<T>`. (Moment of shame!)

Comment: @gsscoder no need for shame! In the interest of pedantic precision, though, I will point out that a Nullable with value `null` is not the same as a null reference.  (However, such a type would also fail to satisfy Thomas Petricek's requirement that the type have only one value.)

Comment: @phoog, +1 you're right. precision is everything in technical discussions. Everything is born because to my eyes because C# methods returning void seemed more procedures than functions. But at least also `System.Void` is a struct and the compiler understand it (avoiding you to explicitly return it for example).

Comment: This is my last implementation: github.com/gsscoder/sharpx/blob/main/src/SharpX/Results/Unit.cs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the best way to define `Unit` for usage from C#. It might differ from how this is done in F# (because in F#, the compiler hides the usage in a way).

However, you can actually find the implementation of F# `unit` in the core library:

- [The public interface is defined in `prim-types.fsi`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/a4e1f7111a6d1410df3f33e7205ee34617006b94/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L15)
- [The implementation is provided in `prim-types.fs`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/a4e1f7111a6d1410df3f33e7205ee34617006b94/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L27)

Here are the key points about the F# `unit` implementation

- It implements `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in the same way to the Rx version
- It is `IComparable` and all values of the `unit` type are equal
- Most importantly, it has a private constructor and so you cannot create a new `unit` value. It also has no *default instance* (unlike the Rx unit) and so in F#, all unit values are actually represented as `null`. However, the language/compiler generally hide this fact.

So, it sounds like the only difference in F# is that it uses the `null` value. If you want to use `unit` explicitly, this might not be the best choice. However, if you have `Unit.Default` then you are ultimately defining a type with two possible values, because it can be either `Unit.Default` or `null` (and so it is not really a unit!)

Comment: +1 This answer my question and points by @Tomas Petricek made things clearer. I also appreciated links to F# source: interesting and useful. I've just a last thing to ask: in the last sentence you say that value can be `Unit.Default` or `null`; but if I define (like in Rx) the type as a `struct` it can't be `null` if not explicitly boxed. Right? Anyway once defined (e.g.: inside a reusable library) I'll not expose this to **Public API**; I plan (for example) to define `Func<T...,Unit>` instead of `Action<T...>` (when absolutely forced and a side effect is not avoidable).

Comment: @gsscoder : "*but if I define (like in Rx) the type as a `struct` it can't be `null` if not explicitly boxed. Right?*" Er, if an object of value type is boxed, it would then be of runtime-type `obj` and it wouldn't be null – value types cannot be null, period (hence the existence of `System.Nullable<>` to sort of simulate this). In any case, he was just remarking on why F# doesn't have an accessible constructor or anything like `Unit.Default` (since F# _doesn't_ use a struct).

Comment: @ildjarn no, when a struct is boxed, it has the *runtime* type of the struct in question.  That is, a boxed int has a runtime type of System.Int32.  The *variable* that holds a reference to the boxed instance may have a *static* type (that is, a compile-time type) of object, System.ValueType, System.Enum if appropriate, or any interface implemented by the struct.  Such a variable can have a null reference, of course.

Comment: `Unit.Default` doesn't necessarily imply a type with two possible values; it could return a null reference.

Comment: @phoog : Poor terminology on my part, apologies.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the clarification. The point about `struct` is very much on spot - I did not realize that (thanks!) and `Unit.Default` could be `null` (but that is a bit weird kind of singleton :-)).

Answer (score 15):

`System.ValueTuple` (without generic argument) is very much *unit* in C#. [The source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueTuple.cs#L34) is open.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this Unit type as a reference:
https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/main/LanguageExt.Core/DataTypes/Unit/Unit.cs

Coming from a functional extension library.