# How to adapt Action<string> into FSharpFunc<string, unit>

Tags: c#, .net, f#

Attempts to pass an Action to F# code is producing the following syntax error in .net 4.6.1, VS2015...

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: 
cannot convert from 'System.Action<string>' to 
'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<string, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>'
```

The attempts are as follows...

```
using Microsoft.FSharp.Core;

....

Action<string> logger = Console.WriteLine;

App.perform(new Action<string>(Console.WriteLine), args);

App.perform(logger, args);

App.perform(new Action<string>(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg)), args);

App.perform((new Action<string>(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg))), args);

App.perform((new Func<string,Unit>(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg))), args);

App.perform(new Func<string,Unit>(Console.WriteLine), args);
```

What is the proper way to pass `System.Console.WriteLine` from C# to F#?

Comment: I'm unclear, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to print to the console from F#?

Comment: As the error message very clearly states, the F# function expects a parameter of type `FSharpFunc<_>`. Why do you keep trying to pass `Action` or `Func` to it?

Comment: I  using a `C#` wrapper to access deployment infrastructure in `VS2015` over an `F#` library I have developed recently. The library accepts a logger for which `Console.WriteLine` fits the bill. One option, I suppose is to access `Console.WriteLine` from within the library directly. However, having a treatment for coercing `void` to `unit` is useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928963/implement-f-interface-member-with-unit-return-type-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FuncConvert` provides various conversion/adapter function, one of them can adapt `Action<string>` to `FSharpFunc<string, unit>`.

```
// Reference: FSharp.Core.dll
var writeLine = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FuncConvert.FromAction<string>(Console.WriteLine);
App.perform (writeLine);
```

The problem is that the `Action<string>` delegate and `FSharpFunc<string, unit>` class are unrelated as far as the runtime is concerned although we know they are conceptually close. C# unfortunately has not added any support to help with F# interoperability.

Comment: Thanks for providing a functional and referenced example. I had belatedly begun to suspected the accommodations, if necessary, would only exist within the F# packaging but finding it would have taken some effort with my current tooling. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI; you could also a have implemented the abstract class `FSharpFunc`. My first try did that but then I found a proper helper method.

Comment: That would have been nice but only in addition. Revealing the `FuncConvert` module and thereby the `F#` solution pattern for this issue was the best answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert `Action<T>` to F# `FSharpFunc<T>`. This is a must, because all Lambda function in F# is using FSharpFunc under the hood, and they are not having the same semantic.